# File-based fixed-record merge sort

Tags: java, mergesort, rags-to-riches

A problem posted here to Code Review prompted me to experiment with a general-purpose merge-sort algorithm for any fixed-length record data.

[**External / File-based mergesort**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60155/external-file-based-mergesort)

[I answered that question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60177/31503), which specifically deals with int values in a file, and proposed an answer that suggested a MappedByteBuffer.

These NIO concepts can be complicated, so I played with the code, and came up with what I believe to be a good solution for a more general case, where the format of the data can be less structured than a simple 4-byte int.

To abstract out the data format from the implementation the code exposes an interface, which allows the format to be exposed to the sort algorithm. The two items on the interface are:

1. `recordLength()`
2. `compare(ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer)`

The `recordLength` is used to manage the byte buffers, and the `compare(...)` method should parse a single record off each byte buffer (which will be correctly positioned already), and return an integer that follows the standard Java contract of negative, 0, or positive if the record on the first buffer is smaller, equals, or larger than the second record.

A 'simple' use case for this code, which assumes the data contains 4-byte int values, would be:

```
private static final class IntParser implements FixedRecordSortFile.RecordParser {

    @Override
    public int recordLength() {
        // int values are 4 bytes.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ByteBuffer bufferOne, ByteBuffer bufferTwo) {
        // parse the int from each buffer, and compare them.
        return Integer.compare(bufferOne.getInt(), bufferTwo.getInt());
    }

}
```

Using this, you can sort a file with:

```
FixedRecordSortFile.sort(Paths.get("path/to/data"), new IntParser());
```

The actual sort code is as follows:

```
package mergesort;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Sort a file of records / fixed-length data using a temporary file.
 */
public class FixedRecordSortFile implements AutoCloseable {

    /**
     * This class is required to construct a FixedRecordSortFile, and it is used to optimize IO, and process and parse the records. 
     */
    public interface RecordParser extends Comparator<ByteBuffer> {
        /**
         * Identify the record length of each record. The IO and buffer positioning operations are affected by this.
         * @return the size of each record
         */
        public int recordLength();

        /**
         * Compare the <strong>contents</strong> at the current position of each buffer.
         * <p>
         * The contract used by this class is that each buffer will be positioned at the start
         * of a record. This record will need to be parsed in a way that allows both records
         * to be compared.
         * <p>
         * It is guaranteed that each buffer will be able to read a full single record from the
         * current buffer position ( buffer.position() + recordLength() <= buffer.limit() ) 
         */
        @Override
        public int compare(ByteBuffer bufferOne, ByteBuffer bufferTwo);
    }

    /**
     *  An approximate size of the memory mapped window we want to use for efficiency.
     *  we will ensure that it is about this size, but also a multiple of:
     *    4K (some filesystem block sizes) - 512 is old-style sector size, 4K is newer.
     *    the record size for the data.
     *  some operating systems require memory mapped IO to align with IO boundaries. 
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_MAPPED_WINDOW = 1024 * 1024;


    /**
     * Sort (in place) a file of fixed-length records defined by the parser.
     * <p>
     * A temp file will also be created in the system/user temp directory which will be the same size as the input file.
     * 
     * @see #sort(Path, RecordParser, Path, int)
     * 
     * @param source The file to sort
     * @param parser The parser that understands the file.
     * @throws IOException if there is an IO problem accessing the file.
     */
    public static final void sort(Path source, RecordParser parser) throws IOException {
      final Path tmp = Files.createTempFile("sort", ".tmp");
      sort(source, parser, tmp, DEFAULT_MAPPED_WINDOW);
    }

    /**
     * Core method for sorting the data in the source path, using the specified temp file.
     * <p>
     * The algorithm used by this sort will create multiple (as many as 3) mappings of the file to memory,
     * and will sort the data in the source file, using space in the temp file as well.
     * <p>
     * Note that the method will scan the file first to ensure it is not already sorted. There is no need
     * to call checkSorted before sort, because sort already calls checkSorted first.
     * 
     * @param source The file to sort
     * @param parser The class that parses, and controls the process
     * @param temp The temp file for sorting in (will grow to the same size as the source, will be deleted at the end).
     * @param memoryWindow How much of the file (this is a hint, not an absolute) will be mapped to memory at any one time
     */
    public static final void sort(final Path source, final RecordParser parser, final Path temp, final int memoryWindow) throws IOException {
        if (checkSorted(source, parser, memoryWindow)) {
            return;
        }
        final long size = Files.size(source);
        final int recordLength = parser.recordLength();
        final long recordCount = size / recordLength;
        final int windowSize = calculateWindow(memoryWindow, recordLength);

        if (recordCount * recordLength != size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                    "The input file size (%d) is not an exact multiple of the record length (%d), and has %d trailing bytes.", 
                    size, recordLength, size % recordLength));
        }
        if (recordCount <= 1) {
            return;
        }
        try (FixedRecordSortFile sorter = new FixedRecordSortFile(parser, size, recordCount, windowSize, source, temp)) {

            // read chunks of SMALLSORT records, and sort them in memory, blocking them in to the temp file.
            sorter.fastSort();

        }
    }

    /**
     * Scan a file, parsing each record, and return true if the records are all in ascending order.
     * <p>
     * This method will use the default Memory window size to memory-map the file
     * 
     * @param data The path to scan
     * @param parser The Record parser that decodes and compares records.
     * @return true if the file is already sorted.
     * @throws IOException if there is a problem accessing the file.
     */
    public static boolean checkSorted(final Path data, final RecordParser parser) throws IOException {
        return checkSorted(data, parser, DEFAULT_MAPPED_WINDOW);
    }

    /**
     * Scan a file, parsing each record, and return true if the records are all in ascending order.
     * 
     * @param data The path to scan
     * @param parser The Record parser that decodes and compares records.
     * @param memoryWindow The suggested size of memory to use for memory-mapped IO.
     * 
     * @return true if the file is already sorted.
     * @throws IOException if there is a problem accessing the file.
     */
    public static boolean checkSorted(final Path data, final RecordParser parser, final int memoryWindow) throws IOException {
        try (FileChannel channel = (FileChannel)Files.newByteChannel(data, StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
            final int recsize = parser.recordLength();
            final long sz = channel.size();
            if (sz % recsize != 0) {
                return false;
            }
            long reccnt = sz / recsize;

            final int winsize = calculateWindow(memoryWindow, recsize);

            final FileBuffer buffa = new FileBuffer(channel, MapMode.READ_ONLY, winsize, sz, recsize, winsize / recsize);
            final FileBuffer buffb = new FileBuffer(channel, MapMode.READ_ONLY, winsize, sz, recsize, winsize / recsize);

            for (long record = 1; record < reccnt; record++) {
                buffa.positionAtRecord(record - 1);
                buffb.positionAtRecord(record);
                int ck = parser.compare(buffa.buffer, buffb.buffer);
                if (ck < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

    }



    // 4K memory blocks are good for IO.
    private static final int IO_WINDOW = 4 * 1024;

    // Find an appropriate multiple of the IO and record size that is about the size of the requested mapping size.
    private static final int calculateWindow(final int approxSize, final int recordlength) {
        int baseio = IO_WINDOW * recordlength;
        final int twoiomask = (IO_WINDOW << 1) - 1;
        while (baseio > approxSize && (baseio & twoiomask) == 0) {
            // the window is larger than wanted, and can be halved and still keep a full multiple of IO_WIN
            baseio >>>= 1;
        }
        while (baseio < approxSize) {
            baseio <<= 1;
        }
        return baseio;
    }

    // FileBuffer class manages/positions a single MappedByteBuffer within a file.
    private static final class FileBuffer {
        private final MapMode mode;
        private final FileChannel channel;
        private final long windowSize;
        private final long size;
        private final int recordLength;
        private final int recordsPerWindow;

        private long mapPosition = -1;
        private MappedByteBuffer buffer;


        public FileBuffer(FileChannel channel, MapMode mode, long windowSize, long size,
                int recordLength, int recordsPerWindow) {
            super();
            this.mode = mode;
            this.channel = channel;
            this.windowSize = windowSize;
            this.size = size;
            this.recordLength = recordLength;
            this.recordsPerWindow = recordsPerWindow;
        }

        final void locateWindow(final long filepos) throws IOException {

            if (filepos >= size) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal file position " + filepos + " in file of size " + size); 
            }

            final long mappos = filepos / windowSize;
            if (mappos != mapPosition) {
                final long pos = mappos * windowSize;
                final long len = Math.min(size - pos, windowSize);
                buffer = channel.map(mode, pos, len);
                mapPosition = mappos;
            }
            buffer.position((int)(filepos % windowSize));
        }

        public void positionAtRecord(final long record) throws IOException {
            final long filepos = record * recordLength;
            locateWindow(filepos);
            buffer.position((int)(record % recordsPerWindow) * recordLength);
        }

        public void copyRecord(final ByteBuffer source) {
            for (int i = 0; i < recordLength; i++) {
                buffer.put(source.get());
            }
        }

        public void copyAll(FileBuffer source) throws IOException {
            long pos = 0;
            while (pos < size) {
                locateWindow(pos);
                source.locateWindow(pos);
                buffer.put(source.buffer);
                pos += windowSize;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            int recs = buffer.limit() / recordLength;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(recs * (recordLength * 2 + 1));
            int pos = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < recs; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < recordLength; j++) {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02x", buffer.get(pos++)));
                }
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    // FastFile manages two FileBuffers for each file/channel.
    private final class FastFile {
        private final Path path;
        private final FileChannel channel;

        private final FileBuffer bufferPrimary;
        private final FileBuffer bufferSecondary;

        FastFile(final Path path) throws IOException {
            this.path = path;
            this.channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.READ);
            if (channel.size() != size) {
                // force the file to the specified size if it was not that size already
                channel.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(1), size - 1);
                channel.truncate(size);
            }
            bufferPrimary = new FileBuffer(channel, MapMode.READ_WRITE, windowSize, size, recordLength, recordsPerWindow);
            bufferSecondary = new FileBuffer(channel, MapMode.READ_WRITE, windowSize, size, recordLength, recordsPerWindow);
        }

    }

    private final long size;
    private final long recordCount;
    private final int recordLength;
    private final int windowSize;
    private final int recordsPerWindow;
    private final RecordParser parser;
    private final FastFile source, workspace;

    // Constructor is private. Instances are not made available outside this class.
    private FixedRecordSortFile(final RecordParser parser, long size, long recordCount, int windowSize, Path source, Path temp ) throws IOException {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.size = size;
        this.recordLength = parser.recordLength();
        this.recordCount = recordCount;
        this.windowSize = windowSize;
        this.recordsPerWindow = windowSize / recordLength;
        this.source = new FastFile(source);
        this.workspace = new FastFile(temp);
    }

    // public close() to conform with AutoClose interface.
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        source.channel.force(true);
        source.channel.close();
        source.bufferPrimary.buffer = null;
        source.bufferSecondary.buffer = null;
        workspace.channel.close();
        Files.delete(workspace.path);
    }

    private void fastSort() throws IOException {
        // perform two-element sort in to temp file.
        smallSort();

        // repeatedly merge the blocks from the temp file, to the
        // main file, then swap them, and repeat until all sorted.
        FastFile from = workspace;
        FastFile to = source;
        FastFile tmp = null;
        for (int bs = 2; bs < recordCount; bs <<= 1) {
            mergeSort(from, to, bs);
            tmp = from;
            from = to;
            to = tmp;
        }

        if (to == source) {
            // copy the sorted data back to the source.
            // but only if the last operation was to the temp file.
            source.bufferPrimary.copyAll(workspace.bufferPrimary);
        }
    }

    // Cycle through the source file, and created sorted blocks of 2 members
    // in the temp file.
    private void smallSort() throws IOException {

        final FileBuffer abuf = source.bufferPrimary;
        final FileBuffer bbuf = source.bufferSecondary;
        final FileBuffer outbuf = workspace.bufferPrimary;

        long outpos = 0;
        final long max = (recordCount >>> 1) << 1;
        for (long rec = 0; rec < max; rec += 2) {
            abuf.positionAtRecord(rec);
            bbuf.positionAtRecord(rec + 1);

            if (parser.compare(abuf.buffer, bbuf.buffer) <= 0) {
                abuf.positionAtRecord(rec);
                bbuf.positionAtRecord(rec + 1);
                outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
                outbuf.copyRecord(abuf.buffer);
                outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
                outbuf.copyRecord(bbuf.buffer);
            } else {
                abuf.positionAtRecord(rec);
                bbuf.positionAtRecord(rec + 1);
                outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
                outbuf.copyRecord(bbuf.buffer);
                outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
                outbuf.copyRecord(abuf.buffer);
            }
        }

        // for an odd number of source records, migrate the last one.
        if (max < recordCount) {
            abuf.positionAtRecord(max);
            outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
            outbuf.copyRecord(abuf.buffer);
        }

    }

    // Called repeatedly with doubling batchsize and swapped from/to...
    private void mergeSort(final FastFile from, final FastFile to, final int batchSize) throws IOException {

        final FileBuffer buffAlpha = from.bufferPrimary;
        final FileBuffer buffBeta = from.bufferSecondary;
        final FileBuffer buffWriter = to.bufferPrimary;

        long posAlpha = 0;
        long posBeta = batchSize;
        long posWrite = 0;

        while (posWrite < recordCount) {
            final long limitAlpha = Math.min(posBeta, recordCount);
            final long limitBeta = Math.min(limitAlpha + batchSize, recordCount);
            while (posAlpha < limitAlpha && posBeta < limitBeta) {
                buffWriter.positionAtRecord(posWrite++);
                buffAlpha.positionAtRecord(posAlpha);
                buffBeta.positionAtRecord(posBeta);
                if (parser.compare(buffAlpha.buffer, buffBeta.buffer) <= 0) {
                    buffAlpha.positionAtRecord(posAlpha++);
                    buffWriter.copyRecord(buffAlpha.buffer);
                } else {
                    buffBeta.positionAtRecord(posBeta++);
                    buffWriter.copyRecord(buffBeta.buffer);
                }
            }
            while (posAlpha < limitAlpha) {
                buffAlpha.positionAtRecord(posAlpha++);
                buffWriter.positionAtRecord(posWrite++);
                buffWriter.copyRecord(buffAlpha.buffer);
            }
            while (posBeta < limitBeta) {
                buffBeta.positionAtRecord(posBeta++);
                buffWriter.positionAtRecord(posWrite++);
                buffWriter.copyRecord(buffBeta.buffer);
            }
            posAlpha = limitBeta;
            posBeta = posAlpha + batchSize;
        }        
    }

}
```

I have some test code that sorts int values and newline-separated 3-letter words and does some benchmarking.

(Note, this code is not for review, but can be useful for testing):

```
package mergesort;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class MakeData {

    private static final byte[][] DATA = buildStrings();

    private static final class IntParser implements FixedRecordSortFile.RecordParser {

        @Override
        public int recordLength() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(ByteBuffer bufferOne, ByteBuffer bufferTwo) {
            return Integer.compare(bufferOne.getInt(), bufferTwo.getInt());
        }

    }

    private static final class StringParser implements FixedRecordSortFile.RecordParser {

        @Override
        public int recordLength() {
            return 4;
        }

        private final String getString(ByteBuffer buff) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                bytes[i] = buff.get();
            }
            return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(ByteBuffer bufferOne, ByteBuffer bufferTwo) {
            return getString(bufferOne).compareTo(getString(bufferTwo));
        }

    }

    private static final FixedRecordSortFile.RecordParser STRINGPARSER = new StringParser();
    private static final FixedRecordSortFile.RecordParser INTPARSER = new IntParser();

    private static final void buildIntFile(final Path path, final long count) {
        Random r = new Random();
        try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(path)))) {
            for (long i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                dos.writeInt(r.nextInt());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static byte[][] buildStrings() {
        byte[][] data = new byte[1000][];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = String.format("%03d%n", i).getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static final void buildFileReg(final Path path, final int reps, final int range) {
        try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(path)))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < range; j++) {
                    dos.write(DATA[j]); // some positive integer
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final void checkStringFileSorted(final Path path, final int reps, final int range) {
        try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis)) {
            byte[] b = new byte[4];
            for (int j = 0; j < range; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
                    dis.readFully(b);
                    if (!Arrays.equals(b, DATA[j])) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Expected value %s at position %d but got %s", Arrays.toString(DATA[j]), range * j + i, Arrays.toString(b)));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static final double toMS(long nanostart) {
        return (System.nanoTime() - nanostart) / 1000000.0;
    }

    private static final void testInt(String name, long count) throws IOException {
        Path data = Paths.get("testSort" + count);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        buildIntFile(data, count);

        double buildTime = toMS(start);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        FixedRecordSortFile.sort(data, INTPARSER);
        double sortTime = toMS(start);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        FixedRecordSortFile.checkSorted(data, INTPARSER);

        double checkTime = toMS(start);

        System.out.printf("Built %10d in %8.3fms, Sorted in %8.3fms, checked in %8.3fms%n", count, buildTime, sortTime, checkTime );
    }

    private static final void validate(int reps, int range) throws IOException {
        Path data = Paths.get("testSort" + reps + "by" + range);
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        buildFileReg(data, reps, range);

        double buildTime = toMS(start);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        FixedRecordSortFile.sort(data, STRINGPARSER);
        double sortTime = toMS(start);

        start = System.nanoTime();
        FixedRecordSortFile.checkSorted(data, STRINGPARSER);
        double checkTime = toMS(start);

        checkStringFileSorted(data, reps, range);

        System.out.printf("Built %10d in %8.3fms, Sorted in %8.3fms, checked in %8.3fms%n", reps * range, buildTime, sortTime, checkTime );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        testInt("Unsorted.dat", 101);
        long[] sizes = {100, 101, 10001, 10000001, 100000001};
        for (int i = 10; i < 500; i+= 13) {
            validate(i,i);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            testInt("Unsorted.dat", 100);
        }
        for (long sz : sizes) {
            testInt("Unsorted.dat", sz);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `smallSort`, you have some duplicated lines in both branches of the `if-else`, which you could extract and do before:

```
int ck = parser.compare(abuf.buffer, bbuf.buffer);
abuf.positionAtRecord(rec);
bbuf.positionAtRecord(rec + 1);
outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
if (ck <= 0) {
    outbuf.copyRecord(abuf.buffer);
    outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
    outbuf.copyRecord(bbuf.buffer);
} else {
    outbuf.copyRecord(bbuf.buffer);
    outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
    outbuf.copyRecord(abuf.buffer);
}
```

Then near the end of the method, the increment in `outpos` is pointless:

> ```
> if (max < recordCount) {
>     abuf.positionAtRecord(max);
>     outbuf.positionAtRecord(outpos++);
>     outbuf.copyRecord(abuf.buffer);
> }
> ```

---

A `for` loop would be more natural for this piece:

> ```
> long pos = 0;
> while (pos < size) {
>     locateWindow(pos);
>     source.locateWindow(pos);
>     buffer.put(source.buffer);
>     pos += windowSize;
> }
> ```

---

The initialization of `tmp` is pointless here, because you overwrite it anyway inside the loop:

> ```
> FastFile tmp = null;
> for (int bs = 2; bs < recordCount; bs <<= 1) {
>     mergeSort(from, to, bs);
>     tmp = from;
>     from = to;
>     to = tmp;
> }
> ```

---

The call to `super()` is pointless in the `FileBuffer` class:

> ```
>  public FileBuffer(FileChannel channel, MapMode mode, long windowSize, long size,
>                 int recordLength, int recordsPerWindow) {
>     super();
> ```

#### Pointless `final` modifiers

What's the point of the `final` modifier on a `private static` method like this one:

> ```
> private static final int calculateWindow(final int approxSize, final int recordlength) {
> ```

Maybe I don't see something but it seems pointless.

Actually, even on `public static` methods, I find the purpose of `final` questionable. When a method is `static`, a sub-class already cannot override it. Sure, a sub-class could still *shadow* it, but is that a realistic concern? If a sub-class shadows a parent's static method, how would that be a problem? A `static final` method seems a bit excessively cautious.